# How to delete old usernames when new usernames are submitted to .txt file?

Tags: php

I have a .txt file on my website called "usernames.txt". In that file, there are usernames of my website members, every time a new member submits his username on my website, it will be saved in that "usernames.txt" file.

Because that file gets big hourly, I have to delete the old usernames (the top = oldest) by myself. And that sucks because when I am in school, I don't have access to my laptop so I can't delete the usernames and that causes problems on my server. (It's hard for me to explain why, but it does make my website slower).

What I want is a script or PHP code or something that automatically deletes the old usernames (let's say the first 40 usernames at the top) and keeps the new ones in the file (let's say the 30 usernames at the bottom) inside the "usernames.txt" file.

Alternatively, I could make use of a script that deletes the first usernames (at the top) every 30 minutes. So only the new usernames will be saved in the "usernames.txt". I know this question sounds strange, but the whole point is to make my server faster.

The file on my website is not called "usernames.txt" actually, but that is smiler to what the file is about. The file on my website saves the users Access Tokens (Facebook Graph thingy) but in the example I gave it is Usernames not Access Tokens. (Because most of the people don't even know what Access Token is, but hopefully everyone knows what Usernames are).

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't use a database?

Comment: I'm curious what sort of site is attracting usernames at such a rate that a file gets too big hourly?   Would the "slowdown" still be a factor if you use a database instead?

Comment: how big is big in this case?

Comment: ... and what operating system...

Comment: ... you definitely want a database.   Otherwise, even with your manual method, how are you going to avoid the situation where your web app writes a new user at the same time you are truncating this file?   You will certainly loose a new user at this point at some time.

Comment: probably depends on the filesize and the workflow. if the file is small and just growing incrementaly he could read the whole file, skip the first records and store the whole file again in the same process as he gathers usernames.

Comment: bit of a bugger getting your user name delete at a whim

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments, I guess I don't need to make a database because 'aksu' has solved my problem! :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that every user is on its own line.

You could use `array_slice` for that purpose. Then you can rewrite file based on sliced values.

```
$filepath = "usernames.txt";
// convert file to array
$file = file($filepath);

// get first 40 elements
$file = array_slice($file, 0, 40);

// rewrite usernames file
file_put_contents($filepath, implode("", $file));
```

You can add [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to handle this script automatically whenever you want, if you have cron on your server.

Edit:

Try this script instead.

```
$filepath = "usernames.txt";
// reverse array to get first elements at the top; convert file to array
$file = array_reverse(file($filepath));

// get first 40 elements
$file = array_slice($file, 0, 40);

// reverse array back; rewrite usernames file
file_put_contents($filepath, implode("", array_reverse($file)));
```

Edit2:

```
$file = file($filepath);

if(in_array($submittedUsername, $file)) {
   $i = array_search($submittedUsername, $file);
   unset($file[$i]);
}

// then save username to the file
```

Comment: Oh my god! that actually worked! I never thought there would be a solution for my problem, but I gave it a try and posted on Stackoverflow!
Thank you very very very much!! I really appreciate it man :)

Comment: Hello aksu, there is one problem :)
The new usernames are not being saved or replaced in the usernames.txt file, the 40 oldest (NOT NEWEST) usernames are there only, what I want is to replace the new usernames with the old usernames when they are submitted :)

Comment: Hi. I made a mistake here on my code. The problem was that it selects only oldest elements in the file. Please try the updated code.

Comment: Hi aksu, I have added the script you edited and it didn't work, the usernames reached 40 and they are still be saved in the bottom of usernames.txt. This is the error I am getting:  Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /home/public_html/index.php on line 325 
And:  Warning: file_put_contents() [function.file-put-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/public_html/index.php on line 325

Can you please tell me what should I fix? I am sorry I am not good at php :)

Comment: Oh, my error, i confused `$file` and `$filepath` together. Pease try now.

Comment: Hi @aksu, can I loop the script? because it's only replacing the FIRST username with the new submitted usernames
For example: If a user submit his username at 01:30 pm, and another user submits his username at 01:31 pm, it will be replaced with the username that was submitted at 01:30 :( 
And what I want is when the user submits his username at 01:31, it will be lined at the bottom of the username (NOT REPLACED WITH) that was submitted at 01:30, is that possible? :)
Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a **session variable** and request it while they are logged in.

Then you don't have to store it in a text file that mixes with every other user's info, possibly leading to *conflicts and I/O blocks* (server requests being delayed while waiting to read/write that file).

1. Login
2. PHP stores Access Token in session for easy access server-side.
3. Token goes away when user closes session.

If you have a very large number of users at any given point (like in the hundreds of thousands - **millions**) you can worry about RAM usage.

And yes as everyone else has mentioned a database would be a useful option here as well.  I would recommend **[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)** for this particular situation.